# not getting prompt after running remote command as ssh

Tags: ssh, command-prompt

How to get prompt from this command

```
ssh abc@10.0.0.1 'ssh xyz@192.168.0.1'
```

After entering password for second ssh command, I am not getting prompt.
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ssh with -t option

```
ssh -t abc@10.0.0.1 'ssh xyz@192.168.0.1'
```